# Neo4j Relationship among nodes

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j graph database has one relationship between nodes i.e. [:KNOWS]. How to add more relationships between nodes other than [:KNOWS] to have more related data in database?

Answer (score 0):

You can create any number of relationships between two nodes - even multiple relationships of the same type. Having multiple relationship of the same type may be interesting if the properties on the relationships differ.

Starting from...

```
alice->[:KNOWS]->bob
```

...it easily can become...

```
alice->[:KNOWS]->bob
alice->[:LOVES]->bob
```

...or even...

```
alice->[:KNOWS]->bob
alice->[:LOVES]->bob
alice->[:IS_MARRIED_TO]->bob
```

Answer (score 0):

Every relationship has a relationship type, which is defined by the user. In Cypher you can just do it in plain text, as James described.

If you are using the Core Java API however, you need to create an enum which implements RelationshipType, and you can then pass any enum value as a RelationshipType.

The :KNOWS relationship is just out there a lot because social networks are a simple way of explaining how graph databases work.

Comment: Thanks Pieter,James for your valuable suggestion but i have one more question... My intention is to calculate the weight of node(No of relationship) like in James example of alice and bob ( alice->[:KNOWS]->bob
alice->[:LOVES]->bob
alice->[:IS_MARRIED_TO]->bob ) weight is 3  So can we calculate weight of node by just one query(Cipher Query) if yes then could you please explain me with one example...

Comment: Well, that's not realy weight because all your relationships have a weight of 1. Normally you'd add a property weight to a relationship and query it like MATCH alice->[relations:KNOWS|:LOVES|:IS_MARRIED_TO]->bob RETURN sum(relations.weight), but in your case you could also just do RETURN count(relations) since all your weights are 1.

Comment: Check out this console example for weight=always 1 --> http://console.neo4j.org/r/cx9wg4

Comment: And this one, where each type of relationship has a different weight assigned to it (KNOWS 0.2, LOVES 0.9 and MARRIED 2.4) --> http://console.neo4j.org/r/9yn2ef

Comment: Thanks Pieter a lot its really helps me a lot while dealing with graph database in my project....

Comment: No problem, you'll get used to it soon enough. You'll soon discover it's actually a very intuitive technology.

Comment: How to update a node can you please write a query cause when i am trying to update node it creates other node.

Comment: START n=node(123) SET n.property='propertyvalue' Note that with updating, you might override an already existing property... How you fetch your node is entirely up to you, I just used start here, but you could do a match and then filter on a property or something.